# ng8 upgrade: ERROR: Unknown version 67 of android

Tags: angular, upgrade

I'm upgrading my angular app from 7.2 to 8.x. And after running the `ng update` command, the dependencies in the package.json are updated. But when I run `ng build` I got the following error message:

```
ERROR: Unknown version 67 of android
An unhandled exception occurred: Unknown version 67 of android
```

In the log file also find the following line:

```
[error] BrowserslistError: Unknown version 67 of android
```

So what's the problem? Where should I debug this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing your **node_modules** directory and reinstalling everything via **npm install**

Comment: Tried. But doesn't work. Do you know where is the "android" from? very confused. Is it related to the new file of `browerslist`?

Comment: @ChrisBao, maybe if you remove package.lock.json it'll work, but make a backup first

Answer (score 3):

I came across the same issue. The flowing is my solution:

1. Delete node_modules and package-lock.json
2. Make sure we include the latest @angular-devkit in the package.json file

   `"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.20",`

   `"@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "^0.803.20"`

   You can get the version info from this page https://github.com/angular/angular-cli
3. At last, run `npm install` again

Answer (score 1):

In my case I needed to change the file **.browserslistrc** to:

```
last 1 Chrome version
last 1 Firefox version
last 2 Edge major versions
last 2 Safari major versions
last 2 iOS major versions
Firefox ESR
not IE 11
```

when I only had this content, I got the error: *BrowserslistError: Unknown version 92 of android*

```
last 2 versions
```